# How to identify which images created first in docker? These are same images but dangling=true

Tags: bash, docker

For example: if we have two dangling=true images

```
REPOSITORY   TAG       IMAGE ID        CREATED        SIZE
<none>       <none>    1e31f1b438dd    2 days ago     1.05GB
<none>       <none>    36ee72bdfe7e    2 days ago     1.05GB


docker inspect --format {{.Created}} 1e31f1b438dd
```

**output:**
2018-10-19T15:02:24.708170378Z

```
docker inspect --format {{.Created}} 36ee72bdfe7e
```

**output:**
2018-10-19T14:57:58.087478393Z

How can we identify which image is created first by bash script?Is it possible can to format these date in bash script?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following bash command:

```
docker image ls --format '{{.ID}}' --filter=dangling=true \
  | uniq \
  | xargs docker inspect --format '{{.Created}} {{.ID}}' \
  | sort -k1n
```

It will produce output like this:

```
2018-09-04T07:29:06.314409018Z sha256:ef1281090a...
2018-09-04T14:29:22.209618542Z sha256:153a2e0699...
2018-10-16T12:21:55.811570654Z sha256:d9efb0a163...
2018-10-19T13:56:47.628606083Z sha256:b1ba405fdb...
```

Explained line by line:

1. Get ids of all dangling images
2. Filter out duplicates (if you tag one image with multiple tags)
3. Get `Created` and `ID` of the images
4. Sort them in ascending order

If you want to get only the oldest image (which has been created first) do:

```
docker image ls --format '{{.ID}}' --filter=dangling=true \
  | uniq \
  | xargs docker inspect --format '{{.Created}} {{.ID}}' \
  | sort -k1n \
  | head -n 1 \
  | awk '{print $2}'
```